# Why is there a base_row_total variable in Quote and Order models?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, sales-order, sales-quote

I'm trying to understand the purpose of `base_row_total` property in Quote and Order sales models.

I still haven't found an example in which it's different from `row_total`.

Can anyone clarify ? I think it's there for tax calculations ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento has the ability to **calculate currencies** based on a conversion rate from store to store. Your base store may be in USD, but you also sell in the UK so you accept GBP.

The `base_row_total` is the **total of that row**, in the **base currency**. Magento applies all line-item discounts at the row-level, so keeping track of the row total is important. Storing it in the base currency is important for exchange rate.

More information can be found in the merchant docs at http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/configuration/currency-setup.html

Comment: Great, it won't be in any future scenario for my small store though! Thank you for clarifying.